# How to configure Keycloak for Superset with Authlib?

Tags: keycloak, apache-superset, authlib

I'm trying to use Authlib to setup Keycloak as SSO for Superset. Everything works fine up until when user is redirected back to Superset. Then this error occured:

```
authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
```

Here's my code:

In **superset_config.py**

```
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Public'
CSRF_ENABLED = True
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        'name': 'keycloak',
        'token_key': 'access_token',
        'icon': 'fa-icon',
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
            'client_kwargs': {
                'scope': 'openid email profile'
            },
            'access_token_method': 'POST',
            'api_base_url': 'https://KEYCLOAK_URL/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/',
            'access_token_url': 'https://KEYCLOAK_URL/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            'authorize_url': 'https://KEYCLOAK_URL/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
        },
    }
]
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = OIDCSecurityManager
```

Here's my **OIDCSecurityManager**:

```
class OIDCSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    def get_oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
        if provider == 'keycloak':
            me = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get("userinfo")
            return {
                "first_name": me.data.get("given_name", ""),
                "last_name": me.data.get("family_name", ""),
                "email": me.data.get("email", "")
            }
```

What can I do to resolve this problem? (this happens on all browser chrome, firefox, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had trouble with the OIDC configs, but this security manager configuration works for me.
Note - I've added roles to my Client configuration in Keycloak, and a mapper so the roles can be picked from the `user info` response.

```
class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):

    def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
        logging.debug("Oauth2 provider: {0}.".format(provider))

        logging.debug("Oauth2 oauth_remotes provider: {0}.".format(self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider]))

        if provider == 'keycloak':
            # Get the user info using the access token
            res = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get(os.getenv('KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL') + '/userinfo')

            logger.info(f"userinfo response:")
            for attr, value in vars(res).items():
                print(attr, '=', value)

            if res.status_code != 200:
                logger.error('Failed to obtain user info: %s', res._content)
                return

            #dict_str = res._content.decode("UTF-8")
            me = json.loads(res._content)

            logger.debug(" user_data: %s", me)
            return {
                'username' : me['preferred_username'],
                'name' : me['name'],
                'email' : me['email'],
                'first_name': me['given_name'],
                'last_name': me['family_name'],
                'roles': me['roles'],
                'is_active': True,
            }

    def auth_user_oauth(self, userinfo):
        user = super(CustomSsoSecurityManager, self).auth_user_oauth(userinfo)
        roles = [self.find_role(x) for x in userinfo['roles']]
        roles = [x for x in roles if x is not None]
        user.roles = roles
        logger.debug(' Update <User: %s> role to %s', user.username, roles)
        self.update_user(user)  # update user roles
        return user
```